# How can I fix the python type error 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to simulate a biochemical system over a period of time, represented by the following equations:

1S + 0T + 0U --> 0S + 0T + 0U

2S + 0T + 0U --> 0S + 1T + 0U

0S + 1T + 0U --> 2S + 0T + 0U

0S + 1T + 0U --> 0S + 0T + 1U

I've written the following function to try and calculate the size of the time increment in the system:

```
from scipy.misc import derivative

def time_step_calc(popul_num, state_change_array, propensity_calc, a0):
    for i in range(len(popul_num)): 
        expctd_net_change = a0*state_change_array[i]
        print("expected net change:\n", expctd_net_change)
        part_propensity_diff = derivative(propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate), popul_num[i]) 
    t_step = epsi*a0 / sum(expctd_net_change*part_propensity_diff)
    delta_t = optimize.fmin(t_step, 0.00012) # take the minimum value of the partial derivative
    print("calculated delta_t:\n", delta_t)
    return delta_t
```

The inputs for the function are as follows: 
popul_num is an array containing the discrete numbers of molecules in the system `popul_num = np.array([1.0E5, 0, 0])`

state_change_array is an array calculated by subtracting the coefficients of each letter on the left-handside of the system of equations from the right-handside.

evaluate_propensity is a different function that calculates the probability of a reation occuring given the discrete number of molecules in the system, the ratio between molecules (in the equations) and the rate of each reaction. This function returns an array of probabilities of each reaction occurring, `a0` represents the sum of this array.

The function above will then be called in a third function that contains a while loop to calculates size of the time increment on each iteration.

I need to calculate the partial derivative of the evaluate_propensity function using different elements of the popul_num array depending on what reaction is firing and how many molecules of each type there are in the system. But at the moment on the line: `part_propensity_diff = derivative(propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate), popul_num[i])`

I get the following error: `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable` (whole traceback below) I've done some reading and I've already made sure that I haven't got any return variable names that are the same as function names but am still struggling to solve it.

```
 File "c:/Users/Mike/visual studio code project/MSc dissertation code/gillespie_paper_simulation2_tau_leaping.py", line 110, in time_step_calc        
part_propensity_diff = derivative(propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate), popul_num[i])
File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\common.py", line 119, in derivative
val += weights[k]*func(x0+(k-ho)*dx,*args)
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

EDIT: link to the documentation for `derivative` 
which is meant to perform the following partial derivation: d(evaluate_propensity)/d(popul_num[i])

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html

EDIT: The propensity_calc function:

```
def propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate):
propensity = np.zeros(len(LHS))
for row in range(len(LHS)):
        a = stoch_rate[row]     
        for i in range(len(popul_num)):
            if (popul_num[i] >= LHS[row, i]):       
                binom_rxn = binom(popul_num[i], LHS[row, i])
                a = a*binom_rxn
            else:
                a = 0
                break
        propensity[row] = a     
return propensity
```

Any suggestions? 
Cheers

Comment: Could you show definition of `derivative`?

Comment: I've imported it from scipy, the first argument is meant to be the function to derive and the second is the variable to be kept constant. I've attached a link to the docs, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes. Looks like `propensity_calc` returns array instead of function. Can you show its definition?

Comment: Added in the function, I want it to return an array for use further on, is that my problem ?

Comment: As I said, `propensity_calc` returns `propensity` which is `numpy.ndarray`, but first argument of `derivative` should be function.

Comment: Ah I see thank you, Is there a way to use derivative with an array, or do you know of another library that will allow me to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by derivative of array?

Comment: I need to do this partial differentiation: bji(x) = daj(x)/dxi, where aj(x) is each element of the array that propensity_calc returns and xi is the discrete number of molecules in that reaction of the system. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: How aj(x) depends on x? In your code `propensity_calc` returns an array, hence it is const.

Comment: yes, that function returns an array, but it is called in a another function that uses a while to update the "popul_num" after each iteration, then calls "propensity_calc" again and recalculates with the new "popul_num" This is done over a specified period of time.

Comment: I see. Then you should store previous values and then calculate derivative like `(val - prev_val)/(x - prev_x)`.